# Combined looping and recursion when implementing Quicksort, using proper Clojure style

Tags: recursion, clojure

In *"The Joy of Clojure", 2nd edition*, code for quicksort is introduced on page 133 that I found hard to digest. I have [rewritten it](https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/47c2303703ba4ecaf3b512cc0f1dab36) to make it clearer (at least to myself).

Here is the original:

```
(defn sort-parts-joc [work]
  (lazy-seq
    (loop [[part & parts] work]
      (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
        (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
          (recur (list*
                  (filter smaller? xs)
                  pivot
                  (remove smaller? xs)
                  parts)))
        (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
            (cons x (sort-parts-joc parts)))))))
```

Here is the rewritten code:

```
(defn sort-parts-explicit-lazy [work]
   (lazy-seq        
      (loop [loopwork work]
         (let [[ part & partz ] loopwork ]
            (if-let [[pivot & valuez] (seq part)]
                  (let [ smaller? #(< % pivot)
                         smz      (filter smaller? valuez)
                         lgz      (remove smaller? valuez)
                         nxxt     (list* smz pivot lgz partz) ]
                        (recur nxxt))
                  (if-let [[oldpivot & rightpartz] partz]
                          (cons oldpivot (sort-parts-explicit-lazy rightpartz))                    
                          []))))))
```

Testing:

```
(require '( clojure test ))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[]])))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[1]])))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[1 2]])))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[1 2 3]])))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[3 2 1]])))
(clojure.test/is (is-sorted (sort-parts-explicit-lazy [[3 3 3]])))
```

So, it works.

Both functions are essentially the same.

However I have a bad feeling about this. The simultaneous use of `recur` and full recursion, with the full recursion path "leaving" the loop in its middle in the same function feels weird, like unstructured code dropping a good, fat GOTO.

Here is the expression tree for reference:

[image: quicksort function expression tree]

We are far from from beta-reduction here. The "reduction" can only be understood using explicit instruction flow semantics. Okay, reality meets platonic ideals.

Is the loop-recur/full-recursion supposed to look like this? Is it a style problem that can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed, this can be viewed as a case of mutual recursion. To demonstrate this I give the following mutually recursive definitions:

```clj
(defn sort-parts [work] (lazy-seq (sp-loop work)))

(defn sp-loop [[part & parts]]
  (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
    (sp-loop ;or recur for tco
      (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
        (list*
          (filter smaller? xs)
          pivot
          (remove smaller? xs)
          parts)))
    (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
      (cons x (sort-parts parts)))))
```

Because `sp-loop` is needed only in one place inside `sort-parts`, we can replace the previous with the following:

```clj
(defn sort-parts [work]
  (lazy-seq
    ((fn sp-loop [[part & parts]]
       (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
         (sp-loop ;or recur for tco
           (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
             (list*
               (filter smaller? xs)
               pivot
               (remove smaller? xs)
               parts)))
         (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
           (cons x (sort-parts parts)))))
     work)))
```

Of course, if we use `recur`, `sp-loop` can be anonymous. But instead of defining and calling an anonymous function which only executes a loop, we can explicitly write a loop, arriving this way at the definition given in the book.

Moving further, noticing that in the mutually recursive definitions there is very little code inside `sort-parts` apart from the call of `sp-loop` (this call is just being wrapped in a `LazySeq`'s thunk), we can define `qsort` using only one recursively defined function and no (explicit) loops, as shown below:

```clj
(defn qsort [xs]
  (lazy-seq
    ((fn sort-parts [[part & parts]]
       (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
         (recur ;or sort-parts for no tco
           (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
             (list*
               (filter smaller? xs)
               pivot
               (remove smaller? xs)
               parts)))
         (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
           (cons x (lazy-seq (sort-parts parts))))))
     (list xs))))
```

And if we drop laziness, we can use just one loop:

```clj
(defn qsortv [xs]
  (loop [done []
         [part & parts] (list xs)]
    (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
      (recur
        done
        (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
          (list*
            (filter smaller? xs)
            pivot
            (remove smaller? xs)
            parts)))
      (if-let [[x & parts] parts]
        (recur (conj done x) parts)
        done))))
```

Finally, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55881144/11419548) you can see a similar case of mutual recursion and laziness but without tail calls.

Comment: That's pretty extensive.

Answer (score 2):

> We are far from from beta-reduction here. The "reduction" can only be
>   understood using explicit instruction flow semantics.

No. You have chosen to interpret `loop` and `recur` in this way, but that is not how Clojure understands them.

- `recur` is simply a flag for a tail-recursive call, functional as you like.
- `loop` is a gloss on defining and applying a function.

We could define `loop` as a macro in terms of `fn`:

```
(defmacro loop [bindings & expressions]
  (let [[bindees values] (->> bindings
                              (partition 2)
                              (apply map vector))]
    `((fn ~bindees ~@expressions) ~@values)))
```

[The real `loop` macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4541) checks the syntax of `bindings`. I've not bothered. And it handles destructuring explicitly. I've left it for `fn` to do.

Comment: Ok. I have actually moved the deconstruction in `loop` further down for "beginner's clarity" after I printed out `work` and noticed that it never changed in the "loop" and that I had better use what's on the left side. And having many things happen at once that I don't really can be sure of and not having "asserts" makes me nervous.

Comment: I get it. So maybe the glossed-over "loop" function should be made explicit, then we could have the recursive call tree TOPF--calls-->LOOPF--calls-->(LOOPF or TOPF). This is more verbose but more expository for beginners.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Clojure is not a pure functional language. My point is that `loop` and `recur` don't make it any less pure. The former is a piece of syntactic sugar simple enough to be expressed as a three line macro. The latter is an implementation hint/instruction. By the way, I'm sorry to say that I don't know what TOPF or LOOPF mean.

Comment: Ah, soory. Just "top function" and "loop function". I should be clearer...